# How do I interpret results of a mixed effect linear regression with 7 independent variables accounting for variability of one dependent variable?

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I have 7 moderators while fitting the mixed effect model using the `metafor` package, my results show many interactions and I am a bit confused on how to present these results. Any help, book or article on this will help. Thanks
[image: inter]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of output. Post the output itself between the ``` delimeters to format it nicel

Comment: @RobertLong I don't understand you, you need my whole output?

Comment: Yes, in R, just highlight the output, copy it, and paste it into your question, and put ``` just before the start, and also at the end.

Comment: You are fitting a model with a **7-way interaction**. It will be very difficult if not impossible to make sense of this. Also, your model has 108 coefficients but you only have 125 data points. Hence, you are completely overfitting your data. You really need to simplify your model (e.g., consider only the main effects, so replace all those *'s with +'s).

Comment: @Wolfgang thanks for the response.  Is there any other possibility of checking for interactions? because I really need to see how their combination influences my outcome.

Comment: An additive model really is not accounting for the heterogeneity (R-square = 5.2%) and I-squared (90%) remains high.

Comment: Maybe examine the two-way interactions then, but you better have some theory before you do this. Also, report ALL tests that you do, not just the ones that happen to be significant. You might also want to read https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.1187 and https://doi.org/10.1002/jrsm.1338.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the model output that is shown, you are doing a meta analysis of 125 studies, with 7 variables of interest. You are fitting a 7-way interaction, and estimaing 108 parameters. Such a model is overfitted and impossible to interpret.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So please how many parameters can be estimated without overfitting the model? there is a possibility I can re-categorize some of my variables levels.

Comment: There is a rule of thumb that a minimum of 10 observations per parameter are needed, so using this you would not want more than 12 parameters. Also, interactions involving any more than 3 parameters are challenging to interpret.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Ok, I will do that. The answers have really been helpful in making me learn lots of new things but what I am investigating really demands that I check for interactions. Funny thing is, I get a very large R-squared when the model is supposedly overfitted and without these variables, the heterogeneity between my studies remains unaccounted for. I guess I will just report as suggested by @Wolfgang

Comment: There is nothing funny about that. You WILL get high R Squared when the model is overfitted, that's guaranteed ! Think about this....pick 3 random numbers, and fit a cubic curve model to them. R^2 will be 100% but the model will be of no use whatsoever for "understanding" these data or predicting new data..